# Blogger comments are messed up from my CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a college student majoring in computer science and web development, so I'm still learning everything.

One of my clients has a blogger she asked me if I could do a couple of things like make a nav bar and link things up and so on. So after I made the nav bar I notice that her comments are all messed up. I'm not sure if it's the CSS in the nav bar or something else.

My code for the nav bar:

```
<style>
#logo-bloglovin:hover,#logo-bloglovin:active { background-position:0 -64px; }

#logo-facebook
{
background-position:-210px 0px;
}

#logo-facebook:hover,#logo-facebook:active { background-position:-210px -64px; }

#logo-instraram
{
background-position:-420px 0px;
}
#logo-instraram:hover,#logo-instraram:active { background-position:-420px -64px; }

#logo-googleplus
{
background-position:-660px 0px;
}

#logo-googleplus:hover,#logo-googleplus:active { background-position:-660px -64px; }

#logo-contact
{

background-position:-880px 0px;
}
#logo-contact:hover,#logo-contact:active { background-position:-880px -64px; }


ul.chicnav {
border: none !important;
display: block;
list-style: none;
}

li{
display: inline-block ;
}

ul.chicnav li a {
width:210px;
height:62px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
border: none !important;
background: url('http://i47.tinypic.com/280nmtx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

ul.chicnav li a:hover {
background-color: transparent !important;
}

</style>

<ul class="chicnav">
<li><a href="http://www.bloglovin.com/blog/3798040/chic-fashion-world" id="logo-bloglovin" > </a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Chic-Fashion-World/248420155275530" id="logo-facebook" > </a></li>
<li><a href="http://instagram.com/borka12/" id="logo-instraram" > </a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/109438806289588533953/posts" id="logo-googleplus" > </a></li>
<li><a href="http://chicfashionworld.blogspot.com/p/contact.html" id="logo-contact" > </a></li>

</ul>
```

The blog lives at [chicfashionworld.com](http://chicfashionworld.com/). I made a test page with some improvement at [chicfashionworldtest.blogspot.com](http://chicfashionworldtest.blogspot.com/). If you have any suggestions for me for me, please let me know.

Comment: Just a note - you might want to have that tinypic picture moved locally in case it is one day removed from tinypic. Also, probably the reason that comments are messed up is due to the ul/li code that you modified.

Comment: @jsanc623 I was planing on doing it on the dropbox I made for her or doing it locally like you said thank you for the reminding me and im going to look at my ul li now

Comment: Would again suggest against dropbox - that's not a valid solution. Host it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's your original code, cleaned up a bit:

```
<style>
#logo-bloglovin:hover, #logo-bloglovin:active{ background-position:0 -64px; }

#logo-facebook{ background-position:-210px 0px; }
#logo-facebook:hover, #logo-facebook:active{ background-position:-210px -64px; }

#logo-instraram{ background-position:-420px 0px; }
#logo-instraram:hover, #logo-instraram:active{ background-position:-420px -64px; }

#logo-googleplus{ background-position:-660px 0px; }
#logo-googleplus:hover, #logo-googleplus:active { background-position:-660px -64px; }

#logo-contact{ background-position:-880px 0px; }
#logo-contact:hover, #logo-contact:active{ background-position:-880px -64px; }


ul.chicnav {
  border: none !important;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

li{ display: inline-block; }

ul.chicnav li a {
  width:210px;
  height:62px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  border: none !important;
  background: url('http://i47.tinypic.com/280nmtx.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

ul.chicnav li a:hover { background-color: transparent !important;}
</style>

<ul class="chicnav">
  <li><a href="http://www.bloglovin.com/blog/3798040/chic-fashion-world" id="logo-bloglovin" > </a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Chic-Fashion-World/248420155275530" id="logo-facebook" > </a></li>
  <li><a href="http://instagram.com/borka12/" id="logo-instraram" > </a></li>
  <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/109438806289588533953/posts" id="logo-googleplus" > </a></li>
  <li><a href="http://chicfashionworld.blogspot.com/p/contact.html" id="logo-contact" > </a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice that 23rd line? `li{ display: inline-block; }`? I would bet that is the cause of your problems. Perhaps modify it to `ul.chicnav li{ display: inline-block; }`. The reason being that you're making ALL the `li` elements on the page `inline-block` - not just the one in the nav.

Comment: thank you that was the problem i'll need to look out for things like that in the future.

Comment: You're very welcome. Remember, try to style globals as baselines or use baseline CSS resets. Then style everything underneath using classes.